# apple push cloud provider server testing

Tags: apple-push-notifications

I have to set up push cloud notification server. I decided to use: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyapns/

The question that i have is how to test the server if i don't have an app which will be connected to the server? Is there any sample apps or services that would display the push notification? I just want to send payload using some sort of script and see if sending is successful or not. How people debug such things? Aren't there any kind of virtual env for such tasks?

I do have certificates and ID's of the app, but not the app it self, since the other people are making it. I do not use MAC, or have iOS device. I did read docs from apple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So eventually i got the right .pem certificate and token of phone with the app-under-dev, phone had to registered as testing one for that app. I just pushed messages and waited for answer unit i got it. Apple do not provide any "easy to use" testing grounds, logs or messages for debugging. Best you can do is to separate pushing service and getting token as much as possible and when you got your hands on app do the raw testing.